# nslookup and dig is working but curl getting errored out on macOS 13(Ventura)

Tags: macos

***Background***

We are using a VPN provider to access our resources deployed on private subnets. All the resources were accessible through a VPN. We intermittently face a DNS issue with macOS 12.6, but after clearing the DNS caches it starts working.

***Problem statement***

We upgraded a few of our machines to macOS 13(Ventura) recently, post the upgrade DNS resolution is working with `nslookup` and `dig` but `curl` and `ping` commands are not working.

**Error**:

```
Could not resolve the host: <private-hosted-zone-endpoint>
Closing the connection
Curl: (6) Could not resolve the host: <private-hosted-zone-endpoint>
```

We were using this command to clear the DNS cache

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

If anyone has any suggestions/workaround please let me know.

Comment: Do you have more than one DNS server in the config, and if so do they all resolve that domain correctly? Is there any DoH or DoT (DNS over somethingorother) in the mix?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. which VPN software you are using?

Comment: @jaume i'm using AWS client VPN.

Comment: Yes, domain resolutions is working as expected with nslookup.

Answer (score 2):

I found the workaround for this issue.
We need to reboot the DNS and clear the cache.

```
dscacheutil -flushcache;
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
sudo killall -9 mDNSResponder mDNSResponderHelper
sudo launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
sudo launchctl start homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq
echo “MacOS DNS cache has been cleared!!!”
```